# Eager versus Lazy Haskell. Infinite lists possible in Eager languages?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, infinite, eager

Apparently it is possible to implement Haskell such that it evaluates eagerly without changing the semantics of the language at all. If that is true, how are infinite data structures handled?

http://csg.csail.mit.edu/pubs/haskell.html

> Therefore, a great deal of time is spent creating and destroying suspended pieces of computation (thunks). All too often, these computations are simple enough that it would be just as easy to evaluate them instead. Faxen and others have used static analysis to expose such opportunities for eagerness. We instead propose using eagerness everywhere, while using mechanisms which permit us to recover if our program is too eager.

The key thing there being "we have mechanisms to recover if our program is too eager". What are these mechanism? How do they permit for infinite data structures and the other aspects of lazy evaluation that I've been led to believe are impossible in an eager language?

Comment: The page you linked to seems to give an overview of the mechanisms. Was there something specific you want clarified?

Comment: Yeah I just realised that when I kept reading. Should have read the whole thing first. I feel like a fool :p what's the SO procedure for when someone makes a mistake like this? Should I delete the question?

Comment: Just closing the question is usually fine. ehird's answer is useful anyway, and it's better to err on the side of preserving information.

Comment: I think a question like this has value, since the linked page is quite lengthy and goes into a lot of detail; a short summary of how it works is a good thing.

Comment: You can create "infinite" data structures in an eager language. For a silly example, you can view Haskell code compiled to C as a C program. If the Haskell program contains an infinite structure, so does the C program.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not quite true: you can evaluate Haskell terms eagerly *if you can prove that they won't diverge*.

For instance, when you see `f x`, you could first execute up to 1,000 steps of *x* (stopping if you reach WHNF (weak head normal form) or an error), and then pass it to *f* — the semantics are preserved, but if you think *x* is going to be evaluated, then you can arrange for this to happen ahead of time as an optimisation.

If `x = fix id`, it'll just give up after 1,000 steps of not going anywhere. If `x = undefined`, it'll cause an error and give up (restoring the original thunk and passing it to *f*). And so on.

If `x = [1..]`, then it might end up reducing it to `1 : 2 : 3 : ... : 999 : 1000 : [1001..]`, reach the limit, and stop there, passing the result to *f*.

Basically: By either proving that an expression cannot diverge, or bounding the evaluation so that things terminate even if it does. No change to the semantics, and possibly a big improvement to performance.

Of course, the downside is that if *x* turns out to be some really expensive computation that *f* only uses half of, you'll spend 1,000 reduction steps wasting time. And in the case of `[1..]`, you could end up using a lot of memory to store a list; if *f* processes the list one element at a time, throwing away the head each time, then you'll waste memory. That's why it's tricky :)

The page you originally linked goes into more detail as to the specific techniques used.